# Prove that $f$ reach an absolute minimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $A$ be a closed and unbounded set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that

$$\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} f(x)=+\infty$$

Prove that $f$ reach an absolute minimum in $A$.

That's a question I've been working for so long but I couldn't solve it correctly.

First of all, I noticed that for all $M>0$ exists $\delta >0$ such that if $||x|| >\delta$ then $||f(x)||>M$. But as $A$ is unbounded, I can't use any result about compactness...

I'm a bit lost. Thank you to everybody for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $x_0$ be any point in $A$ and set $M:=|f(x_0)|+1$. Then, exactly as you did, find $\delta$ such that $f(x)>M$ for all $|x|>\delta$.
Now consider the partition
$$A=(A\cup\{|x|>\delta\})\ \dot{\cup}\ (A\setminus\{|x|>\delta\}):=U_1\ \dot{\cup}\ U_2$$
The question for you is why can the minimum only be achieved on $U_1$ and not $U_2$. Then the result follows from compactness of $U_1$

Comment: Thanks @Surb ! Indeed, $\epsilon>0$ would have been enough, but I felt generous :D

Comment: In fact, there is a more optimal way to solve the problem (see my proof). But I insist on the fact that finally, they are both the same, and your proof inspired my proof... So good job anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

**An other way**

You started well. Let $z\in A$. Take $M=f(z)$ in your proof. Now, $f$ is continuous on $B:=\{\|x\|\leq \delta\}$ which is a compact set. Therefore, there is a $y\in B$ s.t. $$\|f(x)\|\geq \|f(y)\|$$
for all $x\in B$. Now, take $\min\{\|f(y)\|,\|f(z)\|\}$, and we are done.